# installation issue in python-asterisk

Tags: python, asterisk

i have install asterisk version 1.4 than some one suggest to me install python 2.4 and later that show some following error that i have mention below

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/Util.py to Util.pyc SyntaxError: ('future feature absolute_import is not defined',)
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/Manager.py to Manager.pyc File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/Manager.py", line 557 except Asterisk.Manager.ActionFailed as e: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/Config.py to Config.pyc SyntaxError: ('future feature absolute_import is not defined',)
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/CLI.py to CLI.pyc
SyntaxError: ('future feature absolute_import is not defined',) byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Asterisk/Logging.py to Logging.pyc
SyntaxError: ('future feature absolute_import is not defined',) running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/asterisk-dump to 755 changing mode of /usr/local/bin/py-asterisk to 755
```

Comment: You need to explain what you're attempting to accomplish, what exactly you did, and what happened. Just posting an error is not enough to provide any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.4 is too old for the code. Install a newer version of Python 2.x.

Comment: i have install 2.6.6 and 2.7 also but it show same error

Comment: Did you bother using them to install it?

Comment: Post the results of using 2.7.

Comment: here one link can any one check it's my actual problem in python and asterisk    http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=89276